# not able to create child states for xstate

Tags: xstate

I  have created [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-abort-jkrtn?file=/src/useAbortable/machine.ts) to highlight the problem.

I have created a state machine for a react hook abortable fetch.

The only way I could get it to work was to have all the states at the same level:

```js
export interface AbortableSchema {
  states: {
    [AbortableStates.Idle]: {};
    [AbortableStates.Loading]: {};
    [AbortableStates.Succeded]: {};
    [AbortableStates.Error]: {};
    [AbortableStates.Aborted]: {};
  };
}

export const createAbortableMachine = <D>(): StateMachine<
  AbortableState<D>,
  AbortableSchema,
  AbortableActions<D>
> => {
  const context: AbortableState<D> = {
    state: AbortableStates.Idle,
    data: undefined,
    error: undefined
  };

  const abortableMachine = Machine<
    AbortableState<D>,
    AbortableSchema,
    AbortableActions<D>
  >({
    id: "fetchable",
    initial: AbortableStates.Idle,
    context,
    states: {
      [AbortableStates.Idle]: {
        on: { START: AbortableStates.Loading }
      },
      [AbortableStates.Loading]: {
        on: {
          [AbortableActionTypes.Success]: {
            target: AbortableStates.Succeded,
            actions: (context, event) => {
              context.data = { ...event.payload };
            }
          },
          [AbortableActionTypes.Error]: {
            target: [AbortableStates.Error],
            actions: (context, event) => {
              context.error = { ...event.error };
            }
          },
          [AbortableActionTypes.Abort]: {
            target: [AbortableStates.Aborted]
          }
        }
      },
      [AbortableStates.Succeded]: {
        on: {
          [AbortableActionTypes.Reset]: {
            target: AbortableStates.Idle,
            actions: (_context, event) => {
              _context = context;
              return _context;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      [AbortableStates.Error]: {
        on: {
          [AbortableActionTypes.Reset]: {
            target: AbortableStates.Idle,
            actions: (_context, event) => {
              _context = context;
              return _context;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      [AbortableStates.Aborted]: {
        on: {
          [AbortableActionTypes.Reset]: {
            target: AbortableStates.Idle,
            actions: (_context, event) => {
              _context = context;
              return _context;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return abortableMachine;
};
```

But to me, it makes more sense to nest the states like this:

```js
export interface AbortableSchema {
  states: {
    [AbortableStates.Idle]: {};
    [AbortableStates.Loading]: {
      states: {
        [AbortableStates.Succeded]: {};
        [AbortableStates.Error]: {};
        [AbortableStates.Aborted]: {};
      };
    };
  };
}

export const createAbortableMachine = <D>(): StateMachine<
  AbortableState<D>,
  AbortableSchema,
  AbortableActions<D>
> => {
  const context: AbortableState<D> = {
    state: AbortableStates.Idle,
    data: undefined,
    error: undefined
  };

  const abortableMachine = Machine<
    AbortableState<D>,
    AbortableSchema,
    AbortableActions<D>
  >({
    id: "fetchable",
    initial: AbortableStates.Idle,
    context,
    states: {
      [AbortableStates.Idle]: {
        on: { START: AbortableStates.Loading }
      },
      [AbortableStates.Loading]: {
        on: {
          [AbortableActionTypes.Success]: {
            target: AbortableStates.Succeded,
            actions: (context, event) => {
              context.data = { ...event.payload };
            }
          },
          [AbortableActionTypes.Error]: {
            target: [AbortableStates.Error],
            actions: (context, event) => {
              context.error = { ...event.error };
            }
          },
          [AbortableActionTypes.Abort]: {
            target: [AbortableStates.Aborted]
          }
        },
        states: {
          [AbortableStates.Succeded]: {
            on: {
              [AbortableActionTypes.Reset]: {
                target: AbortableStates.Idle,
                actions: (_context, event) => {
                  _context = context;
                  return _context;
                }
              }
            }
          },
          [AbortableStates.Error]: {
            on: {
              [AbortableActionTypes.Reset]: {
                target: AbortableStates.Idle,
                actions: (_context, event) => {
                  _context = context;
                  return _context;
                }
              }
            }
          },
          [AbortableStates.Aborted]: {
            on: {
              [AbortableActionTypes.Reset]: {
                target: AbortableStates.Idle,
                actions: (_context, event) => {
                  _context = context;
                  return _context;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return abortableMachine;
};
```

Loading has child states but if I do that I get the following error message:

> Invalid transition definition for state node 'fetchable.loading':
>   Child state 'succeeded' does not exist on 'fetchable'

Answer (score 0):

When you use state names, they're not absolute; they're relative to the sibling. For example, if you have `"success"` as a state defined at the top-level, then you can only refer to that exact string in a sibling of that state; not in a child of a sibling. Then, you have to refer to it by ID.